# Expand 1 to get to Binomial Theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

Assuming $0\leq \lambda \leq \frac{1}{2}$ show that:
$$1 = (1 + (1- \lambda))^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \lambda^k (1- \lambda)^{n-k}.$$

I understand the general procedure of the binomial theorem, namely that:
$$ (1 + (1- \lambda))^n = \binom{n}{0}1^n (1- \lambda)^0 + \binom{n}{1}1^{n-1}(1- \lambda)^1 + \dots + \binom{n}{n-1}1^1 (1- \lambda)^{n-1} + \binom{n}{n}1^0 (1- \lambda)^n= \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} 1^{n - k} (1- \lambda)^k.$$

What gives me trouble on the one hand is the "trick" to get to
$$1 = (1 + (1- \lambda))^n,$$

on the other I do not know how to switch arround the terms to get $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \lambda^k (1- \lambda)^{n-k}$$ instead of
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} 1^k (1- \lambda)^{n - k}$$.

I am an EE undergrad just getting started with mathematics. Thanks.

Comment: It must be a typo..

Comment: Apparently so, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the basic equation is
$$1 = (\lambda + (1-\lambda))^n.$$
The right-hand side can be expanded as you've shown.

Comment: I understand, so this is a typo. Thank you very much !